# If 1 byte is writen to a pipe and that 1 byte is read from the pipe. Will another read from that pipe be blocking or will it return zero

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pipe

To elaborate more.
I know a read from an empty pipe is by default a blocking call.
The question is if

1. I create a pipe.
2. I try to read 1 byte from the empty pipe in process 1 -> (this read will BLOCK process 1)
3. I write 1 byte to the pipe from another process.
4. read 1 byte from process 1 unblocks.
5. I try to read another 1 byte in process 1 again from the pipe -> (will this read return zero or will it be BLOCKING again until I write again into the pipe via another process?)

Comment: Do you mean **named pipes** right? In any case, I recommend you to implement a short test program to find it out. Surprises and special cases are common (note: you use also *default*). By doing this short test, you get also a toolbox to debut further problems (caching, signals, etc.). Documentation is good, but I trust it only after having tested it explicitly.

Comment: Reads from the "read" end of the pipe will not return 0 unless the pipe is empty and the "write" end of the pipe is fully closed (i.e., all outstanding descriptors for the "write" end have been closed).

Comment: @IanAbbott can you make this an answer. I tried it and it works as you described.